# %F returns no output

Tags: c++, strftime, ctime

I'm writing code to automate writing markup for our web server at work, and I've run into trouble trying to implement an automatic date insertion in the text files using `strftime()` from the `<ctime>` header. Here's the relevant code:

```
if (yen(raw_input))
    {
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        time (&rawtime);
        timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
        strftime(buf, 10, "%F", timeinfo);
        strftime(cuf, 60, "%B %d, %Y", timeinfo);
        date = buf;
        longdate = cuf;
    }
...
ofstream mark;
const string filename = name + date + ".txt";
mark.open(filename);
mark << "{s5_mp3}http://www.####DELETED####.org/media/s5_mp3/" << date << "_" << name_cf << "_Sermon.mp3" << "{\s5_mp3}\n";
mark << hon << " " << name << ": ";
if (is_series) {mark << series << ": ";}
mark << title << "\n";
mark << verse << "\n" << longdate << "\n\0";
mark.close();
```

The first quoted block inserts today's date in two different format into two already initialized char buffers, and then stores them to strings, and the second section writes everything to a file. `date` is in format YYYY-MM-DD(%F), and `longdate` is in format Month DD, YYYY(%B %d, %Y). The problem is that strftime fails to write anything to the char buffer when using %F (determined using debug). If I change %F to the synonymous syntax "%Y-%m-%d", it returns the year and month fine, but the date is two symbols which get boxed out by g++. The perplexing part is that `longdate` works perfectly, so it's not an issue with `timeinfo`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You should read the [standard definition for `strftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/). Particularly the compatibility section that says `%F` was:

> introduced in C99 (only required for C++ implementations since C++11), and may not be supported by libraries that comply with older standards.

Comment: I'm compiling using -std=c++0x, and I've also tested the code by itself using the same options, and it outputs the information perfectly.